# Where are the Kubernetes kubelet logs located for the AWS EKS Clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, amazon-eks

There are previous questions about Self managed Kubernetes clusters located here. But they don't cover the use case for Amazon Linux(AWS EKS provided AMIs)
[Where are the Kubernetes kubelet logs located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113476/where-are-the-kubernetes-kubelet-logs-located)

Where are the kubelet logs for EKS nodes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer for the kubelet EKS use case is: /var/log/messages in the AWS Linux AMI

You can determine this yourself by checking the AWS documentation when asking for Customer Support:

This is how to get to kubelet logs
Read the troubleshooting guide, specifically the CNI Log Collection Tool section.

[AWS EKS Troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html)

AWS has a CNI support tool installed in their EKS AMI liste in the documentation above as being at:

```
/opt/cni/bin/aws-cni-support.sh
```

Go through that script and find these lines:

```
# collect kubelet log
cp /var/log/messages $LOG_DIR/
```

This will allow you to determine how AWS collects the kubelet logs and come up with the file listed above.